# Shared Element Transition not working in android 10(Q) while returning to calledActivity

Tags: android, shared-element-transition, android-10.0

Got this in only android-10(Q) and works fine in android pie and below api levels.
I was trying to work with sharedElement transition. From a recyclerView item to new activity. It works fine when i work with two activities that is., From Activity A -> Activity B and returning from Activity B -> Activity A. While working with three activities A,B & C.

[image: For two activities]

Activity A -> Activity B through sharedElement transition and Activity B -> Activity C without any transitions. After this Activity C -> Activity B -> Activity A.

[image: For three Activities]

SharedElement transition is not working from Activity B -> Activity A.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding these codes in ActivityB's onStop method

```java
override fun onStop() {
    if (!isFinishing && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {    
        Instrumentation().callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(this, Bundle())
    }
    super.onStop()
}
```

I use the method to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work if there's no transition from B->C but only from A->B. So it partially solves the issue. Did you happen to find a solution that would also work for multiple shared element transitions between 3 and more activities?

Answer (score 1):

I actually encountered same issue like OP on Android 10+ (11 dev preview also suffers from it). I spent like 2 weeks on it so I'll try to summarize my findings and a hack how I managed to fix it in my project.

So I found out that if call the code that ppxpp posted as an answer it does help when when the screen rotates (or any other config change).

Then I found out it's better to save all the shared element names into a String array in `onSaveInstanceState()` like this:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        sharedElementList?.run {
            outState.putStringArrayList(PENDING_EXIT_SHARED_ELEMENTS, ArrayList(this))
        }
    }
}
```

where `const val PENDING_EXIT_SHARED_ELEMENTS = "android:pendingExitSharedElements"`
It's a constant defined in [ActivityTransitionState](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityTransitionState.java)

And to get the `sharedElementList` you can call this in onCreate()

```
setEnterSharedElementCallback(object : SharedElementCallback() {
        override fun onSharedElementsArrived(sharedElementNames: MutableList<String>?, sharedElements: MutableList<View>?, listener: OnSharedElementsReadyListener?) {
            super.onSharedElementsArrived(sharedElementNames, sharedElements, listener)
            sharedElementList = sharedElementNames?.toList()
        }
```

}

Next up the activity actually needs to be recreated for this to have effect - so only adding this will make it work if you rotate screen on Activity B.

Therefore I call `recreate()` on Activity B like 500-1000ms after I open the Activity C. That way the transition isn't laggy.

Just be cautious about calling `supportPostponeEnterTransition()` and `startPostponedEnterTransition()` because if they are calling them when entering Activity B, they will be called again after `recreate()`

In general it's enough to call the recreate once so I'm myself keeping a local flag in the Activity B for me to know if the Activity was already recreated or not yet, so that I don't do it unnecessarily too much every time I go from B to C and back.

Overall this is just a high level hacky solution and I was dealing with many more issues having recyclerviews in each Activity which makes things more complicated.

If you find any better please comment, I'd love to hear it but I can't spend any more time on this as two weeks of investigation of Android source code and comparing API28 and 29 has been enough for me :D

Comment: haw to implement this in java

Answer (score 0):

That's because a behaviour change on Android 9: `onStop` is called after `onSaveInstance`, which causes the `transitionNames` not initialized if the `Activity` calls `onStop` before performing the return transition. You can refer to this [page](https://github.com/xjunz/ReturnTransitionPatcher) to learn more about this issue.

Anyway, in order to patch this glitch, you can add this line into your dependecies:

```
implementation 'io.github.xjunz:return-transition-patcher:+'
```

And call this method to patch all activities in the application.

```java
// Call this to patch all activities. 
ReturnTransitionPatcher.patchAll(application)
```