# calling multiple activity in shared element transition in android

Tags: android, android-animation, androidx, shared-element-transition

I have an error while using the android shared element transition.

Implementation I am expecting:

I have three 3 activity A, B, C. Start activity B from A i.e (**A.startActivity(B)**) with makeSceneTransitionAnimation for a image. This animation working fine.

Next Start activity C from B (i.e **B.startActivity(C)** with makeSceneTransitionAnimation). This animation is for **another image with different transitionName**. This also working fine.

Now coming to the error part:

When I hit the back button from Activity C, Activity B pops up with the reverse of makeSceneTransitionAnimation. After I hit the back button from B, it pops up the activity A, But **the makeSceneTransitionAnimation is not happing**.

Thanks,

Rajakumar R

Comment: I had the same issue - and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62834726/1071762 I posted an answer of how I dealt with it (hacked it), so maybe it can give you a hint on the direction to take with this issue

Comment: thanks for the answer